# Galaxy note 8 battery drain with mobile data

Tags: samsung, battery, battery-life, mobile-data, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I've confirmed that battery drain issue in my Note 8 is because of mobile data and hotspot. I have evidence.

Here is battery usage with mobile data and hotspot ON. AOD was OFF

[image: https://imgur.com/0xPqu5M]

As you can see it shows battery usage over 7 hours going from 100% to 35%.

Here is the usage of screen. As you can see it was only on for 2 hours. As I said always on screen is disabled. That leaves 7-2= 5 hours of screen being OFF

[image: https://imgur.com/ArR2DLS]

Now here is 4 hours battery usage going from 100% to 95%. Screen was on only for half hour but mobile data was also OFF. That means my mobile data is literally draining as near as display. That's a huge amount of battery getting wasted. Any ideas? What should I do?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Lbby4]

My note 8 is only 2 weeks old but ive confirmed and its original. Only mobile data seems to be doing bad job (battery charges fast and seems good)

I mean even if LTE consumes high battery it should not consume as much as display.

What is the logic here?

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, I think this should be the expected result considering the device is using **a lot of resources which are mostly power (CPU) hungry**.

- When using mobile data and additionally have mobile hotspot activated, you essentially utilising two communication radios (4g and WLAN) which themselves require considerable power.
- It is mostly like there are some services running in background when there is an active internet connection. (e.g sync, silent updates etc)
- This power we are talking about is coming from the battery hence it becomes very hot, just a symptom indicating it's "working very hard" to supply power to the device' resources and consequently a heavy battery drain is inevitable.
- Although screen is considered to cause a high battery drain when the device is idle, its certainly not the case the the device is active and using its other hardware.

You may want to further analyse the batter statistics with other third-party tools from playstore (e.g battery drain analyser)

Also try to regulate the up-time of your mobile hotspot, to minimise battery usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont notice any overheat in my phone though. Just a little bit while its fast charging but its normal i guess. Is there any app that will automatically turn off hotspot and mobile data when its not used for more than say 10 minutes?

Comment: Oh, just noticed. My mobile hotspot is set to automatically turn off after 20 minutes of inactivity. But it doesnt. Probably something keeps running in background. Ill use 3rd party app to monitor this behavior other than battery manager of my phone

Comment: If it automatically turns off then its ok. But again I doubt it 4g network would   use that much battery, there must be another culprit. Try getting stats with `adb shell dumpsys batterystats` command with [tag:adb]